# Is it possible to publish an API using KrakenDAPI gateway?How is API-key supported by KrakenDAPI gateway?

Tags: krakend

Is it possible to publish an API using krakenD API gateway?How is API-key supported by KrakenD API gateway ?

Answer (score 0):

API-key is only supported in the Enterprise Edition. Open source users have JWT validation.